# I'm making a code to ask for a password that will deny after 3 failed attempts. I am trying to print an attempt counter but don't know where to put it

Tags: python

I've made some code to request the user to enter a password. The user has 3 attempts to get the password correct. If the 3 attempts are up, access is denied. This part works fine, but I am also including an attempt tracker. This will let the user know how many attempts they have left. The problem is, this attempt tracker displays even when access is granted. I'm not sure where I should put the print statement in this code to only display during failed attempts.

```
# Setting variables
correct_password = "Password123!"
attempt_limit = 3
user_input = ""

# While loop to continue if password isn't correct
while user_input != correct_password:
    user_input = input("Enter your password: ")
    attempt_limit -= 1
    print(f"You have {attempt_limit} attempts left") # Portion I am having problems with. If access is granted, this portion still outputs. I need this ignored if access is granted.
    if attempt_limit == 0: # If statement to deny access and break loop once attempts limit is 0
        print("Access Denied")
        break
else:
    print("Access Granted")
```

When access is granted, I want "Access Granted" to display but I also don't want the attempt tracker to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of using a `while` loop is to just use: `while True:` and work out when to terminate the loop within the body somewhere:

```
# Setting variables
correct_password = "Password123!"
attempt_limit = 3
user_input = ""

# While loop to continue if password isn't correct
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter your password: ")
    if user_input == correct_password:
        break
    attempt_limit -= 1
    print(f"You have {attempt_limit} attempts left") # Portion I am having problems with. If access is granted, this portion still outputs. I need this ignored if access is granted.
    if attempt_limit == 0: # If statement to deny access and break loop once attempts limit is 0
        print("Access Denied")
        break
if attempt_limit:
    print("Access Granted")
```

Also, since we have to break out of the loop you need an `if` just afterwards to work out what happened.